# Rye cultivation and rye flour

Tags: food, gardening, cooking, fruits-and-vegetables

In view of the possibility of cultivating rye to become self-sufficient in bread and flour, I am looking for a good estimate of the following quantities:

> 1. the surface of area planted with rye needed to produce 1 kg of rye grain;
> 2. the amount of rye grain needed to produce 1 kg of rye flour.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the *Encyclopedia of Country Living* by Carla Emery, which I cited here before and can warmly recommend to anyone:

> [image]

This makes about 5.5 sqm per kg of rye (grain or flour, doesn't really make a difference).